# Created an API class in python that is failing on the method to return any values

Tags: python, api, microsoft-graph-api

I created this method after running into issues with my token timing out. The call worked when it was just a function and not part of a class. Here is the api class I created to call the msgraph. It successfully gets the token and stores it. I am just trying to call the method of get_users. The error is

```
<bound method msGraph.Decorators.refreshToken.<locals>.wrapper of <msgraph.msGraph object at 0x0197F628>>
```

```py
    class msGraph():
        token = None
        token_expiration = None
        tenantid = None
        user = None
        apiurl = None
    
        def __init__(self, tenantid):
            self.tenantid = tenantid
    
            try:
                self.token = self.gettoken()
                if self.token is None:
                    raise Exception("Request for access token failed.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    
            else:
                self.token_expiration = time.time() + 1800
    
        def gettoken(self):
            try:
                apiurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token".format(self.tenantid)
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                        'client_id': 'xxx',
                        'client_secret': "xxx",
                        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'}
                newdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
                token = requests.post(apiurl, data=newdata, headers=headers).json()
    
            except Exception as e:
    
                print(e)
                return None
    
            else:
                return token['access_token']
    
        class Decorators():
            @staticmethod
            def refreshToken(decorated):
                def wrapper(api, *args, **kwargs):
                    if time.time() > api.token_expiration:
                        api.gettoken
                    return decorated(api, *args, **kwargs)
    
                return wrapper
    
        @Decorators.refreshToken
        def get_users(self):
            try:
                print('trying to get users')
                apiurl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
                authheader = "Bearer {}".format(self.token)
                print(authheader)
                header = {'Authorization': authheader, 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    
                response = requests.get(apiurl, headers=header).json()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return None
    
            else:
                users = response['value']
                userList = []
                for user in users:
                    if "#EXT" not in user['userPrincipalName']:
                        userList.append(user['userPrincipalName'])
    
                return userList
```

This is how I am accessing it from the main script

main.py

```py
    from msgraph import msGraph
    from processemails import userscan
    tenant_id = "xxx"
    company_Domain = "xxx"
    
    
    # Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        api = msGraph(tenant_id)
        userList = api.get_users()
        for user in userList:
            userscan(user, company_Domain, api)
    
        quit()
```

Comment: Code has been updated after the suggestion to move the return of the wrapper indent out one to match the if of the timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to write

```
 userList = api.get_users()
```

with the parenthesis. Without the parenthesis, what you're assigning to `userList` is the function object, instead of the result of calling the function. And a function object is not an iterable, hence your error message.

Comment: I added() and now it says   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mtmcd\PycharmProjects\Confirm4meBatch\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    for user in userList:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Was there any exception printed out _before_ that stack trace ? Your `getUsers()` function will return None if an exception is thrown.

Comment: there was no exception thrown

Comment: I dont even see the output of the print statement in the get_users function

Comment: Inside the wrapper function, I don't know if you have an indentation problem with the posted code... as I see it written, the `return decorated(api, *args, **kwargs)` statement only runs when the time condition is true, otherwise wrapper returns None.

Comment: That is correct. The goal of Decorators class is to only refresh the token after a certain time has passed. Otherwise I want it to use the existing token. The process can take a decent amount of time and the token can/has timed out. this is to try and avoid that

Comment: I understand why you're doing it, and I agree that the call to `api.gettoken` should be under the True case of the `if`, but not the `return decorated(...`. When the time to refresh the token has not yet come, the `wrapper` function never calls the decorated function, control falls off the bottom, and `getUsers()` returns None. Which is why you don't even see the output of the print. Have you tried indenting the `return decorated(...` one step less ?

Comment: Code has been updated. I moved the wrapper return out to match the if of the time. I am now recieving the follow error.

Comment: It is working now! Thank you so much @joao